# asking humans to rank items

Tags: experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, ranking, recommender-system, bradley-terry-model

I have around 50 items and I need to ask human graders to rank them. Is there any good resource on how to design this crowd sourcing task? For example, it will be tiresome to ask humans to rank 50 items at once. Also, considering all possible pairwise comparisons ends up with a huge number (50 choose 2).

I know one can use Plackett-Luce ranking model to obtain full ranks from partial ranks. But, is there any general guideline how to obtain those partial ranks? and how we should design the experiment? As an example, what is a reasonable size for each partial ranking set? how to choose items in a set? should it be uniformly random? or should it follow a particular distribution? I am new into this and would appreciate any guidance.